# Send Timeout Response to user if no response is sent after certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a NodeJS/Express application and am looking to spawn a child-process and get a result to return to the user. If this process takes too long, I want to send the user a timeout message. Here's what I've tried:

```
app.get("/run-process", function(req, res) {
     setTimeout(function(){
         return res.send("Timeout");
     }, 5000)
     // This is to imitate a spawn process that takes too long
     while (true) {
         console.log("Infinite Loop!")
     }
     ...
     Do some other stuff...send response to user.
})
```

Ideally, after 5 seconds, if no response is sent, the timeout function would run and send a timeout message to the user, AND all other code in this $.get function would stop. However, this is not working. Instead, the loop continues indefinitely and the set timeout function isn't stopping the code.

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you reach the `while(true)` nothing else will execute other than the infinite loop.

The call stack is filled with calls to `console.log` and therefore wont ever place the `setTimeout` function in it.

Comment: If this were a spawn child process, would the same be true. How would I accomplish my goal of exiting out of any other process after a certain amount of time?

Comment: If it's a child process, then it's a separate process with its own event loop, so your `setTimeout` callback in the parent process would _not_ be blocked.

Comment: What @Jacob said is correct! if you want to exit out of the request after X amount of time a `setTimeout` is ok just send timeout as a response and `res.end()` that should let the client know the request is over.

Comment: I've tried including this: process.kill(-runner.pid);
          return res.status(400).send('Timeout');
          res.end("Timeout"); in the settimeout function. However, afterwards response does not send to the user and then the spawn process continues. Let's suppose in this case, the spawn process contained an infinite while loop.